# Remove quotes from JSON object for Google Graphs

Tags: json, string, removeall

I have a JSON in this form:
[["Management Information Systems","2","0"],["Marketing","1","1"]]
Google Graphs wants this to be in the following format:

```
 [['Subject', 'Value1', 'Value2'],
 ['Management Information Systems',2,0],
 ['Marketing', 1,1]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You parse the JSON, then run it through code that knows the GG format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally wouldn't use string manipulation to modify JSON, I'd parse the JSON to get a JS object (in your case an array of arrays) and then directly modify that object before converting back to a JSON string.

The following is one way to do it:

```
// your input as a string
var input = '[["Management Information Systems","2","0"],["Marketing","1","1"]]';

// parse to get an object that you can manipulate
var obj = JSON.parse(input),
    i,
    output;    
// loop over the array
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    obj[i][1] = +obj[i][1];  // convert string to number using 
    obj[i][2] = +obj[i][2];  // the unary plus operator
}    
// add the extra element to the beginning of the array
obj.unshift(['Subject', 'Value1', 'Value2']);    
// convert to JSON string
output = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(output);
// ["Subject","Value1","Value2"],["Management Information Systems",2,0],["Marketing",1,1]]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwoo54rp/

Or you can use the [array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var input = '[["Management Information Systems","2","0"],["Marketing","1","1"]]';

var obj = JSON.parse(input).map(function(v) {
      return [v[0], +v[1], +v[2]];
    }),
    output;        
obj.unshift(['Subject', 'Value1', 'Value2']);
output = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwoo54rp/1/

Note that the desired format that you show has single quotes, but although that is valid in a JS object literal or array literal it is not valid JSON. I don't use Google Graphs, but I would assume it either wants a valid JSON string (with double quotes) or it wants a JS object (in which case the quotes aren't really part of the values).

Further reading:

- [Unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B))
- [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: // your input as a string
var input = '[["Management Information Systems","2","0"],["Marketing","1","1"]]';

// parse to get an object that you can manipulate
var obj = JSON.parse(input),
    i,
    output;    
// loop over the array
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    obj[i][1] = +obj[i][1];  // convert string to number using 
    obj[i][2] = +obj[i][2];  // the unary plus operator
}    
// add the extra element to the beginning of the array
obj.unshift(['Subject', 'Value1', 'Value2']); //THE LAST ROW WAS NOT NECCESSARY, IT PRODUCED AN ERROR. GOOGLE GRAPHS REQUIRES IT AS AN ARRAY just obj

Comment: I mentioned that that might be the case. That means you're not actually dealing with JSON (at least not for output), because JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn strings into numbers in Javascript using `parseInt(string)` if you know your input is integer in nature, or `parseFloat(string)` if it might have a fractional part.